# Angular 4.4.6 shared services in lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am googling about a 2 weeks now but cannot find any suitable answer to my question. So I am asking here.

**Description**

**Tools: Angular 4.4.6 and Angular-CLI 1.4.9**

I have fairly simple application that I am working on. It has AuthModule, AdminModule, LayoutModule and SharedModule. Everything works fine if I add all of these modules to the AppModule but, the issue is when I add these modules too the the AppModule then my vender.... size goes way more then 600kb (--aot).

**Explanation of modules.**

**ShareModule**: has some models and services that are common to each module e.g. **HttpService**.
**AuthModule:** contains simple Login and Register components that uses **HttpService** from shared module

So I decided to put them all as lazy loaded modules with routing which is described [here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router). This reduces the size of vendor...js by almost 50% but then then dependencies doesn't work.

Although I referenced SharedModule in LazyLoaded module but still that doesn't solve the issue, dependencies doesn't work. I know, each lazy loaded module creates its own DI tree but it doesn't resolve dependencies other than that has been created and provided inside the lazy loaded module.

As I said in tools section I am using Angular-CLI which has an awesome feature of detecting similar module used twice in some components if so then it creates a common...js for that module. But still issue remains I cannot access the shared service in lazy loaded module.

**Is there a possibility or can anyone point me how to load shared services in lazy loaded modules?**

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you want services from lazy loaded modules to be available as global singletons and available everywhere, implement `forRoot` and import `MyLazyModule.forRoot()` in `AppModule`. This way the providers are registered globally, while the rest is lazy loaded.

See https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot for more details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to link but it doesn't matter if I export it for root or import shared module. Because all the shared services are using shared models within SharedModule so when I try to export services for root it also export all models for root.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. Which is mentioned in agular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules) just didn't get my attention before.

> Do not specify app-wide singleton `providers` in a shared module. A
>   lazy-loaded module that imports that shared module makes its own copy
>   of the service.

What you need to do is do not provide and service from shared module. Just import shared module in lazy loaded module and provide the service from that lazy loaded module.

I hope this will help someone else.

Happy coding. :)

Comment: With this approach can the a lazy loaded modules share the same service? I am getting undefined in the lazy loaded module when trying to access the public properties of the service set by the another module.

Comment: this solutions works but the problem comes when you have information saved into this service/provider. Every time you change from one component to another, even if you have your service loaded in both of them, you lose the info. This is ok for general functions but not to storage data

Comment: Does it mean maybe that this is the only approach to follow and we need to change the way we're saving our info and use some other ways like internalStorage for example?